# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'master')

Tags: reactjs

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        const {
            productState,
            customerState,
            setStateMasterCustomerForm,
            setStateMasterProductForm,
            deliveryRouteState,
            setStateMasterDeliveryRouteForm
        } = this.props
        if (prevProps.customerState.master.data !== customerState.master.data) {
            if (customerState.master.data.length > 0) {
                setStateMasterCustomerForm("customer_no", customerState.master.data[0].customer_no);
                setStateMasterCustomerForm("name", customerState.master.data[0].name);
                if (customerState.master.data[0].remarks !== "" && customerState.master.data[0].remarks !== null) {
                    setStateMasterCustomerForm("tempRemarks", customerState.master.data[0].remarks.split(','));
                } else {
                    setStateMasterCustomerForm("tempRemarks", []);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you try to access some properties of an object while the object is undefined
you get this error

to prevent that you can you optional chaining
`customerState?.master?.data`

it automatically checks if the customerState is null or undefined if this was the case it won't try to access the property